# メンバ関数からクラスの名前を取得する方法

Tags: python

あるクラスのメンバ関数内から、そのクラス名を取得することは可能でしょうか。
教えていただきたいのはPython 3での方法ですが、一応Python 2での方法も教えていただけると幸いです。

### 例

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

という風なクラスがあった時に、`Foo`を取得するといったものです。

Comment: ちなみに、`def __init__(self):`は、必要ないですね。`class Foo: pass` だけでもできます。

Answer (score 9, accepted):

原始的な感じですが、 `__class__.__name__` が使えます。。

```
class Foo:
    def whoAmI(self):
        print( "I am " + self.__class__.__name__)

Foo().whoAmI()
```

Answer (score 4):

[こちら](https://hidelafoglia.wordpress.com/2008/12/09/python%E3%82%AF%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B9%E5%90%8D%E3%81%AE%E5%8F%96%E5%BE%97-__class__-__name__/)に載っていました。

```
class Foo(object):
def __init__(self):
    print(self.__class__.__name__) # >>> Foo

a = Foo()
print(a.__class__.__name__) # >>> Foo
```

Pythonのバージョンは2.7でも3.4でも動きました。